# httpconnection with singleton java

Tags: singleton

I want to implement singleton for httpconnection....
I have a servlet as a server and client side I use android. I have to use the connection many times. Currently, each time I am doing a new connection, but that is not the right way.. So I want to implement singleton for the httpconnection so I can use that instance in each android class..... 
so help me.. what type of code i write..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show some code from what you have, and I can help you more...

Off the cuff, I would say make the httpconnection object a member variable of the class, and any time you're making a new one, reference the member variable instead.

Comment: actully i have a url to connect... n no more code can you tell what should i write.....

Comment: public class Singletone {
 private static Singletone conection = new Singletone();
 
 private Singletone()
 {  
 }

  public static Singletone getInstance() {
  return conection;
  
  }
}

Comment: I mean, take some of the code you have that illustrates the problem and edit it into your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

While binding a singleton with a live `HTTPUrlConnection` instance is good from a reusable practice, but you should also consider how often a call will be made to the server. If your Android application[s] make a lot of connections and need fast response, then there's no point creating a chokehold on such a resource. But if that's not the case, you can simply have an instance variable, and initialise it within the constructor of your particular class. Something like -

```
public SomeClass {
    HTTTPUrlConnection conn = new HTTPUrlConnection(...);
    SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();

    private SomeClass() {}
    public static getInstance() {
       return instance;
    }
}
```

Some might contend why initialise the instances inline and not within the `getInstance` method, but i believe this is best in terms of thread safety. Just Google on Singletons are not good from thread-safety perspective.